# Formatting errors in my LINQ to XML query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to work the kinks out of this LINQ to XML query of stock market data returned via yql from yahoo finance. Several of the fields come in either with misformed data or null values. My current error is:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I've added a check nulls for every element I'm interested in, but the error persists.

If it helps, the highlighted code section that appears to throw the exception is the the block containing the "new" initialization of my data point object. If the XML passed the checks in the query, it would throw an error when nulls are passed to the constructor when initializing the `DailyPricingVolDP`.

```
Func<string, DateTime?> tryToGetDate =
    value =>
    {
        DateTime dateValue;
        return DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateValue)
            ? (DateTime?)dateValue
            : null;
    };

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(addressString);
XElement results = doc.Root.Element("results");

CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime targetDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 25);

var makeInfo =
    from s in doc.Descendants("quote")
    where s.Element("LastTradeDate") != null
       && s.Attribute("symbol") != null
    let dateStr = s.Element("LastTradeDate").Value
    let dateValue = tryToGetDate(dateStr)
    where dateValue != null && (DateTime)dateValue == targetDate
       && s.Element("Open") != null && s.Element("DaysHigh") != null
       && s.Element("DaysLow") != null && s.Element("LastTradePriceOnly") != null
       && s.Element("Volume") != null
    select new DailyPricingVolDP(
        (string)s.Attribute("symbol"),
        (DateTime)s.Element("LastTradeDate"),
        (double)s.Element("Open"),
        (double)s.Element("DaysHigh"),
        (double)s.Element("DaysLow"),
        (double)s.Element("LastTradePriceOnly"),
        (long)s.Element("Volume"));
```

```xml
<quote symbol="AFFM">
  <Ask>0.89</Ask>
  <AverageDailyVolume>6523</AverageDailyVolume>
  <Bid>0.67</Bid>
  <AskRealtime>0.89</AskRealtime>
  <BidRealtime>0.67</BidRealtime>
  <BookValue>4.804</BookValue>
  <Change_PercentChange>0.00 - 0.00%</Change_PercentChange>
  <Change>0.00</Change>
  <Commission />
  <ChangeRealtime>0.00</ChangeRealtime>
  <AfterHoursChangeRealtime>N/A - N/A</AfterHoursChangeRealtime>
  <DividendShare>0.00</DividendShare>
  <LastTradeDate>1/25/2012</LastTradeDate>
  <TradeDate />
  <EarningsShare>-4.491</EarningsShare>
  <ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid />
  <EPSEstimateCurrentYear>0.00</EPSEstimateCurrentYear>
  <EPSEstimateNextYear>0.00</EPSEstimateNextYear>
  <EPSEstimateNextQuarter>0.00</EPSEstimateNextQuarter>
  <DaysLow />
  <DaysHigh />
  <YearLow>0.42</YearLow>
  <YearHigh>2.95</YearHigh>
  <HoldingsGainPercent>- - -</HoldingsGainPercent>
  <AnnualizedGain />
  <HoldingsGain />
  <HoldingsGainPercentRealtime>N/A - N/A</HoldingsGainPercentRealtime>
  <HoldingsGainRealtime />
  <MoreInfo>cnprmiIed</MoreInfo>
  <OrderBookRealtime />
  <MarketCapitalization>9.2M</MarketCapitalization>
  <MarketCapRealtime />
  <EBITDA>-34.5M</EBITDA>
  <ChangeFromYearLow>+0.18</ChangeFromYearLow>
  <PercentChangeFromYearLow>+42.86%</PercentChangeFromYearLow>
  <LastTradeRealtimeWithTime>N/A - &lt;b&gt;0.60&lt;/b&gt;</LastTradeRealtimeWithTime>
  <ChangePercentRealtime>N/A - 0.00%</ChangePercentRealtime>
  <ChangeFromYearHigh>-2.35</ChangeFromYearHigh>
  <PercebtChangeFromYearHigh>-79.66%</PercebtChangeFromYearHigh>
  <LastTradeWithTime>Jan 25 - &lt;b&gt;0.60&lt;/b&gt;</LastTradeWithTime>
  <LastTradePriceOnly>0.60</LastTradePriceOnly>
  <HighLimit />
  <LowLimit />
  <DaysRange>N/A - N/A</DaysRange>
  <DaysRangeRealtime>N/A - N/A</DaysRangeRealtime>
  <FiftydayMovingAverage>0.5639</FiftydayMovingAverage>
  <TwoHundreddayMovingAverage>1.4051</TwoHundreddayMovingAverage>
  <ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage>-0.8051</ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage>
  <PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage>-57.30%</PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage>
  <ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage>+0.0361</ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage>
  <PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage>+6.39%</PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage>
  <Name>Affirmative Insur</Name>
  <Notes />
  <Open />
  <PreviousClose>0.60</PreviousClose>
  <PricePaid />
  <ChangeinPercent>0.00%</ChangeinPercent>
  <PriceSales>0.03</PriceSales>
  <PriceBook>0.12</PriceBook>
  <ExDividendDate>12-Dec-08</ExDividendDate>
  <PERatio />
  <DividendPayDate>31-Dec-08</DividendPayDate>
  <PERatioRealtime />
  <PEGRatio />
  <PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear />
  <PriceEPSEstimateNextYear />
  <Symbol>AFFM</Symbol>
  <SharesOwned />
  <ShortRatio>0.20</ShortRatio>
  <LastTradeTime>1:34pm</LastTradeTime>
  <TickerTrend>&amp;nbsp;======&amp;nbsp;</TickerTrend>
  <OneyrTargetPrice>6.00</OneyrTargetPrice>
  <Volume>200</Volume>
  <HoldingsValue />
  <HoldingsValueRealtime />
  <YearRange>0.42 - 2.95</YearRange>
  <DaysValueChange>- - 0.00%</DaysValueChange>
  <DaysValueChangeRealtime>N/A - N/A</DaysValueChangeRealtime>
  <StockExchange>NasdaqNM</StockExchange>
  <DividendYield />
  <PercentChange>0.00%</PercentChange>
</quote>
```

Comment: Do you do any parsing in the constructor of `DailyPricingVolDP`?

Comment: You should definitely start by splitting up your LINQ query in more manageable parts. For instance, you can first perform the query (_don't_ create your `DailyPricingVolDP` objects within the query), and then afterwards you can loop over the result (e.g. with a `foreach`) creating one `DailyPricingVolDP` in each iteration. That way it is _much_ easier to debug step by step, and see exactly where you parsing fails.

Comment: @w0lf None.. no parsing in the DailyPricingVolDP at the moment.

Comment: @Nailuj I'm doing that now. I was thinking the same, it got, clunky.

Comment: What's your culture setting? Doubles formatted with dot (`.`, as opposed to comma `,`) might be causing the problems.

Comment: @jimmy_keen I edited my code above to include a couple lines before the start of my original posts' code, culture setting included..

Comment: It's just a guess, but will it work if you write similar parsing functions for your constructor parameters? I don't think that Linq to XML is capable of parsing a double from `NULL` or `string.Empty`, which will be the value of the empty elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those null checks you are doing in your query are pointless, (just about all) those elements are present in the XML, but many of them are empty.  You are attempting to parse empty strings  and that fails giving you the error.  You should give us a sample XML that is representative of what you actually have (i.e., has values in them).  If this is what you have, you are performing the wrong kind of checks.

I've restructured the query like this and I've marked where the exception is occurring:

```
var query =
    from quote in doc.Descendants("quote")
    let lastTradeDate = (DateTime)quote.Element("LastTradeDate")
    where lastTradeDate == targetDate
    let symbol = (string)quote.Attribute("symbol")
    let open = (double)quote.Element("Open") // EXCEPTION: empty string to a double?
    let daysHigh = (double)quote.Element("DaysHigh") // DITTO
    let daysLow = (double)quote.Element("DaysLow") // DITTO
    let lastTradePriceOnly = (double)quote.Element("LastTradePriceOnly")
    let volume = (long)quote.Element("Volume") // no Volume element exists, null check might be appropriate
    select new DailyPricingVolDP(symbol, lastTradeDate, open, daysHigh, daysLow, lastTradePriceOnly, volume);
```

Comment: This is mostly a comment just to point you in the right direction.  If we can get XML representative of the actual XML, then I can offer a real solution.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that I might need to check for null, as well as empty string.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
s.Element("Open") != null
```

does not do what you think it does. If there is an element `Open`, even looking the same as in your example (`<Open />`) - that condition is true. Element `Open` is present, and it is not null. It just **doesn't have value** (or to be precise, it has value of **empty string**, `""` - which is causing your format exceptions).

In your `where` clause you should change conditions to

```
s.Element("Volume").Value != ""
```

in order to prevent attempts of parsing empty-valued elements.

---

Quick example. What does this tiny program prints?

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse("<quote><Open /></quote>");
var open = xDoc.Descendants("quote").First().Element("Open");
Console.WriteLine(open == null);
Console.WriteLine(open);
```

That's right. `False` followed by `<Open />`.

Comment: Thanks. I'd give it to ya but it came down to timing I guess.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh: Timing? I don't think I follow you.

Comment: I'd give you the answer, sir. Came down to the fastest gun. Next one.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh: oh, by timings you meant that Jeff's answer came faster/first? Some strange clock you are using :-)

Comment: Oh, it's a clock issue? I should reset my system clock then I guess. :)